# update / merge and update a subset of columns pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have `df1`:

```
  ColA  ColB   ID1    ColC   ID2
0    a   1.0  45.0     xyz  23.0
1    b   2.0  56.0     abc  24.0
2    c   3.0  34.0  qwerty  28.0
3    d   4.0  34.0     wer  33.0
4    e   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
```

`df2`:

```
  ColA  ColB   ID1 ColC   ID2
0    i     0  45.0  NaN  23.0
1    j     0  56.0  NaN  24.0
2  NaN     0   NaN   fd  25.0
3  NaN     0   NaN  NaN  26.0
4  NaN     0  23.0    e  45.0
5  NaN     0  45.0    r   NaN
6  NaN     0  56.0  NaN  29.0
```

I am trying to update df2 only on columns which wil be a choice= `['ColA','ColB']` where `ID1` and `ID2` both matches in the 2 dfs.

Expected output:

```
  ColA   ColB   ID1  ColC    ID2
0    a    1.0  45.0   NaN   23.0
1    b    2.0  56.0   NaN   24.0
2  NaN      0   NaN    fd   25.0
3  NaN      0   NaN   NaN   26.0
4  NaN      0   23.0    e   45.0
5  NaN      0   45.0    r    NaN
6  NaN      0   56.0  NaN   29.0
```

So far I have tried:

```
u = df1.set_index(['ID1','ID2'])
u = u.loc[u.index.dropna()]
v = df2.set_index(['ID1','ID2'])
v= v.loc[v.index.dropna()]
v.update(u)
v.reset_index()
```

Which gives me the correct update(but I loose the Ids which are NaN) also the update takes place on `ColC` which i dont want:

```
    ID1      ID2    ColA    ColB    ColC
0   45.0    23.0    a       1.0     xyz
1   56.0    24.0    b       2.0     abc
2   23.0    45.0    NaN     0.0     e
3   56.0    29.0    NaN     0.0     NaN
```

I have also tried merge and combine_first. cant figure out what is the best approach to do this based on the choicelist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `merge` with `right` join and then [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
choice= ['ColA','ColB']
joined = ['ID1','ID2']
c = choice + joined

df3 = df1[c].merge(df2[c], on=joined, suffixes=('','_'), how='right')[c]
print (df3)
  ColA  ColB   ID1   ID2
0    a   1.0  45.0  23.0
1    b   2.0  56.0  24.0
2  NaN   NaN   NaN  25.0
3  NaN   NaN   NaN  26.0
4  NaN   NaN  23.0  45.0
5  NaN   NaN  45.0   NaN
6  NaN   NaN  56.0  29.0

df2[c] = df3.combine_first(df2[c])
print (df2)
  ColA  ColB   ID1 ColC   ID2
0    a   1.0  45.0  NaN  23.0
1    b   2.0  56.0  NaN  24.0
2  NaN   0.0   NaN   fd  25.0
3  NaN   0.0   NaN  NaN  26.0
4  NaN   0.0  23.0    e  45.0
5  NaN   0.0  45.0    r   NaN
6  NaN   0.0  56.0  NaN  29.0
```

Comment: 1 question, the id names in both my original dataframe are different, would need left_on and right on, in that case should i include all the keys in c?

Comment: @anky_91 - I think for simplier code is best rename columns for same in both dataframes. Because left_on and right_on duplicated columns - same values only different columns names.

Answer (score 2):

here's a way

df1

```
  ColA  ColB   ID1    ColC   ID2
0    a   1.0  45.0     xyz  23.0
1    b   2.0  56.0     abc  24.0
2    c   3.0  34.0  qwerty  28.0
3    d   4.0  34.0     wer  33.0
4    e   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
```

df2

```
  ColA  ColB   ID1 ColC   ID2
0    i     0  45.0  NaN  23.0
1    j     0  56.0  NaN  24.0
2  NaN     0   NaN   fd  25.0
3  NaN     0   NaN  NaN  26.0
4  NaN     0  23.0    e  45.0
5  NaN     0  45.0    r   NaN
6  NaN     0  56.0  NaN  29.0


df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID1','ID2'], left_index=True)[['ColA_x','ColB_x']]
df2.loc[df3.index, 'ColA'] = df3['ColA_x']
df2.loc[df3.index, 'ColB'] = df3['ColB_x']
```

**output**

```
  ColA  ColB   ID1 ColC   ID2
0    a   1.0  45.0  NaN  23.0
1    b   2.0  56.0  NaN  24.0
2  NaN   0.0   NaN   fd  25.0
3  NaN   0.0   NaN  NaN  26.0
4  NaN   0.0  23.0    e  45.0
5  NaN   0.0  45.0    r   NaN
6  NaN   0.0  56.0  NaN  29.0
```

Comment: Thanks, i will check i n a while and let you know. Bdw, the prob is i have a lot of such columns and not only 2 as in the example. :)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to still be the issue in `0.24` where `NaN` merges with `NaN` when they are keys. Prevent this by dropping those records before merging. I'm assuming `['ID1', 'ID2']` is a unique key for `df1` (for rows where both are not null):

```
keys = ['ID1', 'ID2']
updates = ['ColA', 'ColB']
df3 = df2.merge(df1[updates+keys].dropna(subset=keys), on=keys, how='left')
```

Then resolve information. Take the value in `df1` if it's not `null`, else take the value in `df2`. In recent versions of python the merge output should be ordered so for duplicated columns `_x` appears to the left of the `_y` column. If not, sort the index

```
#df3 =  df3.sort_index(axis=1)  # If not sorted _x left of _y
df3.groupby([x[0] for x in df3.columns.str.split('_')], axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.ffill(1).iloc[:, -1])

  ColA  ColB ColC   ID1   ID2
0    a   1.0  NaN  45.0  23.0
1    b   2.0  NaN  56.0  24.0
2  NaN   0.0   fd   NaN  25.0
3  NaN   0.0  NaN   NaN  26.0
4  NaN   0.0    e  23.0  45.0
5  NaN   0.0    r  45.0   NaN
6  NaN   0.0  NaN  56.0  29.0
```

Comment: so i tried this logic, using `df3 = df2.merge(df1[updates+keys].dropna(subset=keys), on=keys, how='left',suffixes=('','_y'))` and 
`df3.groupby(df3.columns.str.strip('_y').tolist(), axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.ffill(1).iloc[:, -1])` since i had underscores in col names as `Col_A` , `Col_B`, didnt work. :(

Comment: @anky_91. In that case you could add some "rarer" suffixes (less likely to match a random string in your columns) to the merge, try adding `suffixes=['_lmerge', '_rmerge']` and then `.groupby(df3.columns.str.replace('_lmerge|_rmerge', ''), axis=1)` with the same logic. Though it seems you already found your answer.

Comment: I would try doing that again and depending on performance i might select the best one. :) thanks a lot for reading your time out for my query. :) Yes the answer by jez works pretty well in the real dfs.